# Load custom theme in specific page / post in wordpress plugin (PHP)

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, plugins

I am developing a plugin and I want to show my custom HTML CSS codes on a page or post with a shortcode.
I have this template:

```php
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Raw page
 */

get_content();

?>
```

and this code on my class:

```php
add_shortcode('my-shortcode', 'callback');
...
public function callback(){
   include('view/form.php');
}
```

now how can I load this template from my function?

Answer (score 2):

Use wordpress function `get_template_part`.

Check ref here - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/

And, another suggestion, does your call back/ short code really required ? You can simply write your logic in your primary template file (where you wrote as raw file).
Then put your logic/conditions there and can include different template parts as per your need.

Comment: Sorry, I did not get my answer, I want to override the theme and use my template on the whole page

Comment: you are already using - 'Template Name: Raw page' right ?
and in your page content you will paste the shortcode, as it seems. And inside that shortcode function you are trying to include 'view/form.php'

My suggestion was instead of doing this rounding thing.... in  'Raw page' ... use  'get_template_part' function to include  ''view/form.php''